# What's the difference between cudaMalloc() and cuMemAlloc()?

Tags: cuda

Both `cudaMalloc()` and `cuMemAlloc()` can apply memory of device. So what's their difference ?

I'm studying CUDA framework, and trying to understand difference between CUDA runtime API and CUDA driver API.

Comment: They come from different APIs. That is the difference

Answer (score 4):

CUDA has two "base" APIs, that is, two base sets of functions to interact with a CUDA GPU.  These two APIs are referred to as the "driver API" (documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html)) and the "runtime API" (documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html)).

`cudaMalloc()`, along with most functions that begin with `cuda` belong to the runtime API.

`cuMemAlloc()` along with most functions that begin wtih `cu` but not `cuda` belong to the driver API.

The programming guide has sections discussing both [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api) and [runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-c-runtime), although the runtime API is largely used for demonstration in the programming guide.

The two APIs have considerable symmetry - you would not ordinarily mix them in the same program.  For basic usage, you can do anything you would expect in CUDA (e.g. manage device memory, launch kernels, copy data) using either the driver API or the runtime API.  To punctuate this, [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/vectorAddDrv/vectorAddDrv.cpp) is the basic vectorAdd sample code realized using the driver API, and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu) is the same realized using the runtime API.

Once you get into the details, of course, there are numerous differences.  To pick just one random example, the driver API allows you to create multiple [contexts](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#context) per GPU, if that is something you would want to do.  This would normally not happen with  a runtime API application.

For beginners, the conventional wisdom is that the runtime API is the place to start.  Most [introductory trainings](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) will have the runtime API in view, and the runtime API is usually less verbose than the driver API.

So if you are writing a "runtime API application" you would use `cudaMalloc()`.  If you were writing a "driver API application" you would use `cuMemAlloc()`.  However functionally, they do essentially the same thing - allocate device memory and return a pointer or handle to it.